# In-memory elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, in-memory

I have a scenario where I want to query database once and after that want to cache the whole data in memory.

I got the suggestion for in-memory elastic search, I have googled it understand what it is and how can I implement it in my **spring boot** application, but I didn't find any appropriate solution.

Any suggestion on this like how can I implement this in my spring boot app and what would be the approach.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be an [in-memory storage type in Elasticsearch in 1.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/index-modules-store.html#store-memory), but it has been removed in 2.x and later versions. If your working set is small enough it might be mapped to memory in full, but you cannot really control that other than having enough memory.

If you want to run an embedded / in-process Elasticsearch with your Spring Boot application that feature was [removed in 5.x and this blog post explains why](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-the-server).